# HERE API traffic line is not clearly visible on the route

Tags: javascript, angular, here-api

I am using HERE API in my application. Calculating route using it. The traffic line is clear all the path except the one which is under the route( Green line traffic is not visible due to Blue line ). Is there any option I can get the traffic in the Blue line itself.

[image]

Comment: which HERE API you're using for traffic?

Comment: Can you please let us know the API you're using for this?